# C# WPF How can I have multiple DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am very new to WPF so despite finding other similar threads, my code is a little different so I don't know how to apply those solutions to mine.

```
<grid>
    <CheckBox
        x:Name="sortChk"
        Content="Sort Variables"
        IsChecked="{Binding SortVariables}"
     />
    <b:FlatButton  Command="{Binding ClickCommand}">
            <TextBlock Text="Compare" FontSize="13"></TextBlock>
    </b:FlatButton>

</grid>
```

Code behind looks something like this

```
string dataset1FullPath = null;
string dataset2FullPath = null;
string dataset1FilePath = null;
string dataset2FilePath = null;
public bool SortVariables { get; set; }

public SingleCompareWindow(string path1, string path2)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    dataset1FullPath = path1;
    dataset2FullPath = path2;
    dataset1FilePath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path1);
    dataset2FilePath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path2);

    //DataContext = this;
    DataContext = new DataCompareVM(dataset1FullPath, dataset2FullPath, dataset1FilePath, dataset2FilePath, SortVariables);
}
```

You can see that I have commented out DataContext = this. If I dont comment it out and remove the other DataContext, then my SortVariables variable will take the value of the checkbox. If I have the other DataContext for the button click, then the checkbox will not bind. I need it to bind as I pass it as a parameter to DataCompareVM().

I'm very new to WPF and MVVM so forgive my ignorance.

Comment: `SortVariables` should then be a Property of DataCompareVM if you want your Checkbox bound to that. A two-way binding then will update the Property's value in the ViewModel when the checkbox is ticked/unticked. Also remember to raise a propertychanged event when a different value is set.

Comment: I did it and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't have more than one DataContext for a WPF control, you should move your properties to the ViewModel.

Comment: Well, you can set a child control to a different DC ... not exactly setting two DCs to _one_ control but still ...

Comment: Yes you can do that but since he is using the MVVM pattern it would be much clearer if he used one DataContext.

Comment: I totally agree. I just wanted to say that if we wanted to be nitpicky, it is indeed _possible_ to have more than one DataContext used in one single control. I am not saying "you should" :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have different data contexts for different elements. But here you're trying to replace the same, window data context.

What you can do is use the named element. Replace your commented line with:

```
sortChk.DataContext = this;
```

Now, for the longest answer: you're not really doing MVVM here. As Fildor mentions, you should instead move the SortVariables property to the DataCompareVM ViewModel.

Since you seem to be struggling with MVVM, I believe reading my introductory book will help you get things straight: [Learn WPF MVVM](https://leanpub.com/learnwpf).

Comment: I moved the SortVariables property to DataCompareVM and it is working as I wanted. Thanks. Out of curiosity since I'm new to MVVM, does the fact that I pass parameters to DataCompreVM(...my parameters...) break the MVVM pattern?

Comment: No. The MVVM pattern is a community-built pattern and it has many variants. Your path parameters don't break the MVVM pattern.